# AWS VPC CIDR IP Address Subnet Calculation

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, subnet, vpc

I have a current vpc with the cidr 192.168.0.0/16 and subnets
"192.168.0.0/24", "192.168.1.0/24","192.168.4.0/24", "192.168.5.0/24"

- Now I want to create a NEW VPC but I am not sure what CIDR IP to use.
- I want to keep the same 192.168 .. however as I am new to all this I cannot identify which other CIDR I can use that will NOT overlap my first vpc cidr.
- once I choose that CIDR, I also need to create 4 subnets from it (like I did for my first VPC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General recommendation for VPC CIDRS is in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-sizing-ipv4):

```
- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

So you can use any of these. Often, people use VPC CIDRs from the first range. So if you would like to do this as well, you could choose any CIDR from below (increment **second digit** if you want to use /16):

```
 - 10.0.0.0/16 
 - 10.1.0.0/16
 - 10.2.0.0/16
 - 10.3.0.0/16
 - ....
 - 10.255.0.0/16
```

From these, to get subnets (/24), you increment **third digit**. For example, for VPC CIDR `10.0.0.0/16`, your subsets would be:

```
 - 10.0.0.0/24
 - 10.0.1.0/24
 - 10.0.2.0/24
 - 10.0.3.0/24
 - ....
 - 10.0.255.0/24
```

The individual resources in your subsets, e.g. instances, will get IPs using the **forth digit**.

Comment: I want the new cidr in 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 range so please suggest accordingly for that, thank u

Comment: @Myra Sadly, you can't have second, non-overlapping from `192.168` as your current VPC (192.168.0.0/16) uses all this range.

Comment: then I can I have something like 192.x which will work?

Comment: @Myra This is not a recommend range. From 192.x, you should only use 192.168 as explained in the AWS docs.

Comment: @Myra To keep using 192.168, you have to make your VPC CIDRS smaller. Instead of /16, use /20. But then, calculating all the ranges and subsets is not as easy to do as for /16. The easiest is `10.x`, thus its most commonly used.

Comment: oh I got that. But I cannot use the 10.x as I have it on another vpc already. So I think im gonna go with 172.19.0.0/16 instead and have the subnets as 172.19.1.0/24, 172.19.2.0/24, 172.19.3.0/24 and 172.19.4.0/24 .. would that be fine?

Comment: @Myra Yes. `172.19` will work as well. But, its unlikely you've used 255 of all available ranges for `10.x`. So if you are using `10.0.0.0/16` already, other non-overlapping will be `10.1.0.0/16`.  If this one is also used, then next non-overlapping is `10.2.0.0/16` and so on.

Comment: great, thanks! Also, just another quick q: I cannot use something like 192.168.x.0 or 192.168.0.x ? if no why is that?

Comment: @Myra You can, but this will reduce the size of your VPC. If you use 192.168.x.0, your VPC cidr will be very small (/24) which means that there will be only 255 addresses for the subnets. With `192.168.0.x` it will be even smaller. Not sure if its not too small to use for VPC. Its better to use 10.x, or 172.16-31 as its very easy to use and operate on.

Comment: ty! what if I go with 192.168.4.0/22 as my main vpc cidr which gives 1022 available addresses and then use the subnets  192.168.4.0/24, 192.168.5.0/24, 192.168.6.0/24 and 192.168.6.0/24 .. it wont overlap right? see http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.4.0&mask1=22&mask2=24

Comment: @mgb Yes. So one VPC would be `192.168.4.0/22`. The second VPC `192.168.8.0/22`. Both with their respective subnets of size of `/24`.

Comment: no I am saying that the cidr for my second vpc would be 192.168.4.0/22 .. and the 4 subnets: 192.168.4.0/24, 192.168.5.0/24, 192.168.6.0/24 and 192.168.6.0/24 for it. I would keep my main vpc as 192.168.0.0/16 which already has its own subnets.

Comment: @mgb You can't keep your `192.168.0.0/16`. Its too big. It takes all the available space in range `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255`. You have to change it so smaller one, e.g. `/20`, `/22` if you don't want overlaps.